# HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found

Tags: asp.net, .net, content-management-system, dotnetnuke

trying to install DotNetNuke 7.02 but it throws error in browser:

HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

i'm entering this url: `http://localhost/dnnInstall` but it doesn't work, i followed all settings and configuration options from a YouTube video.

installed programs are VS 2010, Sql server 2008, IIS 7.5

Comment: `dnnInstall` is the name of your virtual directory?

Comment: yes it is, C:/dnnInstall

Comment: followed this video for installation
www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBatw8mgPrg

Comment: `C:/dnnInstall` is a physical folder name, what is the virtual directory in IIS called?

Comment: same name for virtual directory too

Comment: i clicked test settings in IIS console manager, it says

The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that <domain>\<computer_name>$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

Comment: have you tried simply http://localhost or even http://localhost/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, with your site selected, you should see on the right a couple of link to navigate to your site. It will look like :

> Browse xxxxxx on *:80 (http)

Where xxxxxx is your actual path, does it work if you click that?